# two differents fastcgi_cache_valid value for nginx

Tags: nginx, caching

I use `fastcgi_cache` in nginx and I want to use two different period of time caching for different requests.

For example:

```
    if ($request_uri ~* "/(api/1|api/2)")
        {
           set $no_cache 0;
           set $cache_valid 5m;
        }
    ...
    
    fastcgi_cache_valid 200 $cache_valid; // it's not work
    
    fastcgi_cache_valid 200 1m; // it's work
```

How i can use two different `fastcgi_cache_valid` time values?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use variables with the `fastcgi_cache_valid` directive. If your upstream API web app is under your control, you'd better make it return `X-Accel-Expires: 0` HTTP header for the `/api/1`, `/api/2` and other requests that shouldn't be cacheable. If it isn't, I think your only way is to use two different `location` blocks with different `fastcgi_cache_valid` directives.